# JSON stringify not working as expected while trying to extract a response

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a response in this format:

[image]

I want to extract the `error` key and I tried the below code:

```
  console.log('errorResponse', JSON.stringify(errRes.error)).
```

It returns

```
"javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException: [{\"ReturnCode\":0,\"counter\":\"\\\\\\\\UCM1-PUB.ciscoctg.com\\\\Cisco CallManager\\\\AnnunciatorOutOfResources\"},{\"ReturnCode\":0,\"counter\":\"\\\\\\\\UCM1-SUB-1A.ciscoctg.com\\\\Cisco CallManager\\\\AnnunciatorOutOfResources\"},{\"ReturnCode\":101,\"ErrStr\":\"\\\\\\\\IMP1-SUB-1B.ciscoctg.com\\\\Cisco CallManager\\\\AnnunciatorOutOfResources;\",\"counter\":\"\\\\\\\\IMP1-SUB-1B.ciscoctg.com\\\\Cisco CallManager\\\\AnnunciatorOutOfResources\"}]"
```

[image]

But when I try to filter out from the `error` key the ones with `ReturnCode` other than 0, I get the error:

```
ERROR TypeError: errRes.error.filter is not a function
```

I tried:

```
console.log('errorResponse', JSON.stringify(errRes.error.filter(val => val.ReturnCode !== 0)))
```

I am not able to figure out how to extract it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1:**

[image]

**Edit 2:**

[image]

Comment: How is this related to `JSON.stringify()` and `angular`?

Comment: The content of `.error` is a string. Why should `.filter()` work in this case?

Comment: please show me the output of this `console.log(errRes.error)` and `console.log(typeof errRes.error)`

Comment: @0brine I have added it in the edit, It prints 2 times, the 2nd time it show `undefined`. As you can see in the screenshot , its printed 2 times for the same line of code

Answer (score 0):

please use this method
alert(JSON.stringify(error.json()));

Answer (score -1):

try this, idk why but it seems to work
`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(errRes.error).replace("javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException: ", "")).filter(...)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it, but its giving this error: `core.js:6162 ERROR TypeError: JSON.parse(...).filter is not a function`

Comment: ok please show me the output of 
`console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(errRes.error).replace("javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException: ", "")))`

Comment: I have updated and added the screenshot above in `Edit 2`. It prints 2 times, 1st time it prints the out and 2nd is undefined. Both are in the screenshot